# Disable Xcode 9 app automatically building in background

Tags: interface-builder, xcode9

Since updating to Xcode 9 I am seeing it build the app automatically in the background when I open xib file.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 6):

Disabling "Automatically Refresh Views" did the trick (un-check box).

While having a XIB file open go to Editor menu and uncheck that option.

You may need to close Xcode to have current build stop then re-open.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Xcode 9? This screenshot you shared doesn't belong to Xcode 9.

Comment: Yes this is from Xcode 9.0 (9A235), I got to this menu by first opening up a Xib file in the interface builder then the Editor menu items change based on the file context.

Comment: Hi there, i did it, but Xcode 9 doesnt stop, it continuous building... There is another thing that had to do ?? Thanks

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde you can try close Xcode and re-open. I have not seen any more building when opening Xib files after un-checking this box.

Comment: Yeah, i did that after i wrote here, because i disabled and it continuous building... i cancel the process by quitting the xcode, now it is Ok again! Thanks!